# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFWorkbook ERROR

Tags: java, excel, hssfworkbook

Getting 'NoClassDefFoundError' for the following code.

```
public static void exportTable(JTable table, File file){

        try{
                TableModel model = table.getModel();                    

               // FileWriter out = new FileWriter(file);

                HSSFWorkbook workBook = new HSSFWorkbook();
                HSSFSheet sheet = workBook.createSheet();
                HSSFRow headingRow = sheet.createRow(0);
                short rowNo = 1;
                for(int i=0; i < model.getColumnCount(); i++) {
                //out.write(model.getColumnName(i) + "\t");
                 headingRow.createCell((short)i).setCellValue(model.getColumnName(i));
                }
               // out.write("\n");
                for(int i=0; i< model.getRowCount(); i++) {
                     HSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(rowNo);
                     for(int j=0; j < model.getColumnCount(); j++) {
                        //out.write(model.getValueAt(i,j).toString()+"\t");
                          row.createCell((short)j).setCellValue(model.getValueAt(i,j).toString());
                    }
                     rowNo++;
               }
                  try{
                      FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
                      workBook.write(fos);
                      fos.flush();
                  }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
                      e.printStackTrace();
                      System.out.println("Invalid directory or file not found");
                  }catch(IOException e){
                      e.printStackTrace();
                      System.out.println("Error occurred while writting excel file to directory");
                  }


        }catch(Exception e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Invalid File Location!");
        }
    }
```

I'm getting this error:

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFWorkbook

Comment: Did you import the library that contains HSSFWorkbook? Edit your question to include your import statements.

Comment: Give the entire code pls, NoClassDefFoundError comes when 1 or more `.class` files go missing during run time, but right now cannot really figure out why you would get such an error, with the provided chunk of code.

Comment: @MarsAtomic this is Exception not compile error so import statement should be ok according to my understanding